# Бесконечно добавлять файлы в Input type file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Вот HTML

```
<form>
   <input name="file" id="myfiles" multiple type="file">
</form>
```

Вот JS

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector("#myfiles");
var pullfiles=function(){
      var files = fileInput.files;
      var fl=files.length;
      console.log(fl);
  }
 document.querySelector("#myfiles").onchange=pullfiles;
```

При повторном добавлении файлов в #myfiles  console.log(fl)  выдает количество только новых добавленyых файлов. То есть к ранее добавленным файлам новые не добавляются. В итоге на почту приходят только последние добавленные файлы. Нужно чтобы на почту приходили все файлы. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сохранять добавленные файлы в контейнер (`files`) а при отправке собирать файлы из него

```js
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#myfiles');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

const files = [];
const pushFiles = function(){
    // files.push(...Array.of(...fileInput.files).filter(f => !files.some(f2 => f2.name == f.name)));
    files.push(...fileInput.files);
    
    list.innerHTML = files.map(f => f.name).join('<br>');
};

const sendFiles = function(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append('files', file);
    }
    
    console.log(formData.getAll('files'));
};

document.querySelector('#myfiles').onchange = pushFiles;
document.querySelector('#send').onclick = sendFiles;
```

```html
<form>
   <input name="file" id="myfiles" multiple type="file">
</form>
<div id="list"></div>
<button id="send">Отправить</button>
```

При необходимости добавлять только уникальные, приходящий список файлов надо фильтровать.